# Create functions and variables inside one for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

No matter how hard I am trying to get the right loop using JavaScript for this I fail. As you can see in the code below I have several things repeating an I want to put it in a for loop. But is there actually a way to get all these things into one for loop and how?

As you can see I have: sub1(), push1, "mydiv"+1 and other things repeated... Thank you in advance and sorry cause I am rookie :)

```
function sub1() {
    push1++;
    var myfield = document.createElement("textarea");
        myfield.name = "rex" + 1 + push1;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = myfield.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("mydiv"+1).appendChild(div);
}
function sub2() {
    push2++;
    var myfield = document.createElement("textarea");
        myfield.name = "rex" + 2 + push2;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = myfield.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("mydiv"+2).appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Use a formal argument, e.g., `function sub(n) { ...`? the only thing that won't handle is the variables. For that, you can use an object, e.g., `varHolder["push"+n]++`

Comment: Should she use array? Instead of push1 and push2

Comment: Can you give a few more hints what you want to do? Do you need vars to access anything (push1, push2, ...) or is it enought to create a new `<div>` with a `<textarea>` inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var push = [];

function sub(num) {
    push[num] = (push[num] || 0) + 1;
    var myfield = document.createElement("textarea");
    myfield.name = "rex" + num + push[num];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = myfield.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("mydiv"+num).appendChild(div);
}

sub(1);
sub(2);
```

Comment: This is exactly the thing that make my headache go away. Hope this will help someone else too...